# Python Regular Expression to Identify City Names Out Of Strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Using regular expression in Python 3.4, how would I extract the city names from the following text below?

```
replacement windows in seattle wa
basement remodeling houston texas
siding contractor new york ny
windows in elk grove village
```

Sometimes the city name before it has `\sin\s`, sometimes it doesn't.  Sometimes it has a general word like 'windows', 'remodeling', ... anything.  Sometimes there is no state full name or state abbreviation at the end.

Is there a single regular expression that can capture these above conditions?

Here's what I've tried so far but it only captures 'seattle'.

```
import re

l = ['replacement windows in seattle wa',
     'basement remodeling houston texas',
     'siding contractor new york ny',
     'windows in elk grove village'
    ]
for i in l:
    m = re.search(r'(?<=\sin\s)(.+)(?=\s(wa|texas|ny))', i)
    m.group(1)
```

Comment: I don't think this is generally possible. Use a list of city names. Those can easily be found with google and the likes. Turn that list into a set and look up individual tokens in that set.

Comment: @Jarad it could be possible for a single word city names. https://regex101.com/r/dZ1iN5/3

Comment: @tobias_k I currently do it that way - list of cities, state abbreviations, state full, counties, countries.  The problem I'm encountering is that some locations are misspelled, or not in my list, or abbreviated (mpls, stl, etc.), or begin with 'fort' or 'ft' or is '{word} village', or are too general like 'hope', 'in' (for indiana), etc..  I was hoping for one universal regex logic to apply to each line but based on the responses so far, it doesn't sound like it exists.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Well, it depends on the problem. Certainly there is no regex to match, e.g. all American, Japanese and African city names, but for those "yellow pages US city names" it _might_ work. Maybe there is a regex that fit's your body of text, but to say so your example is too small. BTW, it seems the location is always last; have you tried just taking the last few words of each line?

Answer (score 2):

What you are after is not possible with regular expressions. Regular expressions need string patterns to work. In your case, it would seem that the pattern either does not exist or can take a myriad of forms.

What you could do would be to use a search efficient data structure and split your string in words. You would then go through each word and see if it is in your search efficient data structure.

Comment: What if my pattern was the entire phrase AFTER the word '\sin\s' but BEFORE a state abbreviation or full name state (wa|ny|tx|washington|texas)?  May I ask what that regex would be?  I've tried to figure that out but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: @Jarad: It would be something along `\sin\s(.+?)(wa|ny|tx|washington|texas)`, however, the last bit would grow a lot the more states you throw in, making it ugly to read and maintain. Also, performance wise it might be better to simply use the approach I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

l = ['replacement windows in seattle wa',
     'basement remodeling houston texas',
     'siding contractor newyork ny',
     'windows in elk grove village']

p = re.compile(r"(\w+)\s(?:(wa | texas | ny | village))", re.VERBOSE)

for words in l:
    print p.search(words).expand(r"\g<1> <-- the code is --> \g<2>")
```