# How to find cities, counties, and their abbreviations in a string using Python NLTK

Tags: python, regex, nltk, naivebayes

I am working to categorize posts from a [ride sharing Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/250502971675365/) by offering or seeking, origin and destination, and date and time.
People will post things like:

> Offering: From SF to south west la (Torrance) Leaving around 6 or 7 on this Thursday night aka tomorrow

```
 and
```

> Offering: SFO--->LA (Beverly hills area) Thursday 9am 30$ gas

Using regular expressions I clean up the text:

> offering from sf to south west la torrance leaving around 6 or 7 on this thursday night aka tomorrow

```
and
```

> offering sfo to la beverly hills area thursday 9am 30 gas

I then store the new cleaned post in a mysql database.

I have been advised to remove locations and replace them with a meta word before creating my training set for naive bayes (suggestions on other algorithms welcome). I check for places, such as ucla (which includes city & county abbreviations such as 'sf'), cities, and counties. I would like to use Python's NLTK library to remove the locations, replace with a meta word, while still keeping track of which location corresponds to which meta word.

```
#check if post contains a city name
#param post is an array containing post_id and post text
def checkForCities(con,post):
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT id,city FROM CITIES;")
            #keep track of number of locations found as all locations are represented by the same word
            location_num = 0
            clean_post = post[1]
            for i in range(cur.rowcount):
                row = cur.fetchone()
                if clean_post.find(row[1].lower()) != -1:
                 #using replace instead of regex..not sure which is better...
                 new_post  = new_post.replace(row[1].lower(),'LOCATION_NAME')
                 location_num+=1
                 insertNewPostIntoLocationTable(con,post[0],new_post,row[0],location_num,Locations.Cities)
return new_post
```

With the code above (checkForPlaces function is not shown, but practically identical), the second post would become:

> offering LOCATION to LOCATION LOCATION area thursday 9am 30 gas.

keeping track that the first location corresponds to sfo, the second to la, and the third to beverly hills.

1. As you can see sf is an abbreviation of San Francisco. When I clean the text the first time before putting it in the database, should I replace all instances of San Francisco with SF or all instances of SF with San Francisco? I am currently doing the former because I was incorrectly replacing abbreviations too often (Maybe my regex just needs work?).
2. Alternatively it'd be a lot easier if I could just create a list of all the cities and have some NLTK function tell me if the city or abbreviation exists in the post. Does such a thing exist?
   Bonus Question: How to parse out the dates and times (they appear in every imaginable format)?

You can find more example posts [here](https://www.sunjaydhama.com/projects/rideshare/test.txt)

Comment: This question is more or less asking the same thing as [this other SO question][1].


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111126/python-regular-expression-to-identify-city-names-out-of-strings

Comment: StanfordCoreNLP's NER (Named Entity Recognition) Tagger tags tokens as locations, date and time with remarkable accuracy. I'm not sure how to do it in Python/NLTK but its quite straightforward in Java with CoreNLP.